# How to setup Django settings.py with django-neomodel

Tags: python, django, neo4j

I am currently learning Django and trying to connect it to neo4j's graph database. Here for I am using [Django-neomodel](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/django-neomodel).

However I can't seem to find where I put the following line in settings.py:

```
NEOMODEL_NEO4J_BOLT_URL = os.environ.get('NEO4J_BOLT_URL',
    'bolt://neo4j:test@localhost:7687')
```

Can I just place this anywhere in the file?

Comment: You need to put that line above any code that refers to `NEOMODEL_NEO4J_BOLT_URL`, but apart from that it doesn’t matter where you put it.

Comment: To answer your question, I can say **Yes**, but a small structure in your codes is very important, especially your `settings.py`! Gather variables having the same contexts or coming from the same module, etc ... **more precisely** as @Alasdair said, **Put it above any code that refers to the same module**

Comment: If I would place it, just above Installed Apps, would this be considered the proper structure? Oh and thanks for the very fast replies!

Comment: Anywhere, above codes related to `django-noemodel`. so yes